# Stacking multiple tables vertically using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datatables, union

I have 3 tables that are have identical columns.

```
FY2015
A B C
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4

FY2016
A B C
3 4 5
4 5 6
7 8 9

FY2017
A B C
1 3 5
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

What would be the best way to create a table FY_ALL?

```
FY_ALL
A B C
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 3 5
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `union all`:

```
select a, b, c from FY2015 union all
select a, b, c from FY2016 union all
select a, b, c from FY2017;
```

You can use `create table as` or `insert into` to populate another table (depending on whether or not the table already exists).